# How do I enable movement trail

Tags: super-mario-maker

I saw a video of someone using Mario Maker and when they would press "Play" and run around and then die or press "Edit", it would show the path of where Mario was moving.

How do I enable this? Is it something I have to unlock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you return to create mode, tap the small Mario icon next to the Play clapperboard in the bottom left-hand corner.

<s>The option is unlocked after playing for 9 days. [Details](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/super-mario-makers-creation-tools-take-nine-days-t/1100-6429740/)</s>

**UPDATE:** The 1.0.1 patch for the game changes the conditions for various unlocks. [Details](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1110137)

> Update 1.01 made it so that doing a lot of editing after a delivery is queued will make it be delivered early. –  [Powerlord](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87105/powerlord)

[image]

Comment: There is no Mario icon next to it. Is it something I have to unlock?

Comment: Yes, you have to unlock it. I don't know what the conditions are, but it eventually showed up for me as I continued to unlock more creation tools.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have that icon. If no one posts an answer that includes how to unlock it, I'll accept this or I'll accept it straight away if you edit in how to unlock it.

Comment: @Chippies Unlock conditions added to answer

Comment: "9 days" is not the unlock condition anymore, given that I unlocked it on my second day of play, and the game's only been out for three.

Comment: @CloudyMusic It's in the ninth delivery.  Update 1.01 made it so that doing a lot of editing after a delivery is queued will make it be delivered early.